# Error: Invalid Token

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am developing an application in which i found the error in the manifest file.

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- <activity android:name=".activity.HomeFragment"/> -->
    <!-- <activity android:name=".activity.MessagesFragment"/> -->


    <!-- Admission Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".activity.AdmissionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.HomeFragment" />
    <!-- Admission Activity -->
    <activity android:name=".activity.OverViewActivity" />
    <!-- <activity android:name=".activity.Tab1Fragment"/> -->
    <!-- <activity android:name=".activity.Tab2Fragment" /> -->
    <activity android:name=".activity.MessagesFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.AboutActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.FriendsFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.ContactFragment" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.CampusFragment" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />


</application>
```

**Error:**

```
Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

What could be possibly wrong.

Comment: Where is the <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.packagename"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Comment: @kgandroid I have missed the manifest tag in xml. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this first in your `manifest` .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="add package name"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
.....

   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: @user3532292 Move ahead

Answer (score 0):

you using this line as Two times,

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is copyed from other place and then pasted, the format of code may not be "utf-8", try hand typing the code again, or you can move the mouse to the wrong layout, click the right mouse button to select "Source" and then select "Format". I'm not sure about this, wish I could help you.